# knockout js dropdown with intital selection

Tags: knockout.js

I have a drop down list in knockout js which is bind with list of objects. I want to make default selection in the dropdown list. Can anyone tell me how to make the default selection in knockout drop down list?

my html code

```
<select data-bind="options: availableCountries,
               optionsText: 'itemcapacity',
               value: selectedCountry"></select>
<pre data-bind="text:ko.toJSON(selectedCountry,null,2)"></pre>
```

following is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/2BnQk/2/

I want to make itemcapacity:'High Cap' as the initial selection in the dropdown list. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to do some logic yourself at the point where you define your observable. Here's an example that will just choose the first item in the list where `itemcapacity` is High Cap:

```
var highCapItem = null;
for ( var i = 0; i < choices.length; ++i ) {
    if ( choices[i].itemcapacity === 'High Cap' ) {
        highCapItem = choices[i];
        break;
    }
}
this.selectedItem = ko.observable( highCapItem );
```

If it doesn't find any matching items, Knockout will just revert to the first item in the list.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2BnQk/3/

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the optionsValue as which value will be selected.

```
<select data-bind="options: availablItems,
                   optionsText: 'itemcapacity',
                  optionsValue: 'id',
                   value: selectedItem"></select>
 <pre data-bind="text:ko.toJSON(selectedItem,null,2)"></pre>
```

You can set your item like this:

```
var AppViewModel = function() {
    this.availablItems = ko.observableArray(choices);
        this.selectedItem = ko.observable(8); //Make the selected default id as 8
};
```

Example project:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ysusx/

Answer (score 1):

In your jsFiddle,

Just change

`this.selectedItem = ko.observable();`

to

`this.selectedItem = ko.observable(choices[1]);`

Comment: I cant just hard code with choices[1] option because sometimes I may get more than 2 choices and the object that has itemcapacity='High Cap' may not be the second item in the list. There is one more scenario, in which i wont get the 'High Cap' item at all, in that case first element will be shown as default selection in the drop down list.